# Finding missing value in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, missing-data

I am very(!) new to R and try to find out how to code something which I can solve in Excel in 30 sec. - so forgive me if the question might be a bit trivial...

I have two variables with two values like

```
x= (3,4);
y= (300, 500)
```

How much would be `x` if `y=400`?

Comment: Curious, how would you do that in Excel?

Comment: Actually I should have said Numbers (macs spreadsheet program - so I am not sure if Excel has the same functions). The function is called 'Forecast', with the value  to be compared, then you add two comparison columns, in my case they would each just have two values.

Answer (score 3):

You want

```
x= (3,4)
y= (300, 500)
approx(y,x,400)$y
[1] 3.5
```

Just a note $y and $x are built into the function so they are not related to your variables.  If you need extrapolation use approxExtrap from Hmisc package

Answer (score 2):

You could write your own rescaling function to map values from one range to another

```
rescale <- function(x, inrange, outrange) {
    (x-min(inrange))/diff(range(inrange)) * diff(range(outrange)) + min(outrange)
}    

rescale(400, c(300,500), c(3,4))
# [1] 3.5
```

It's a bit of an overkill, but you could do it with `lm` as well

```
x <- c(3,4)
y <-c(300, 500)
predict(lm(x~y), data.frame(y=400))
#   1 
# 3.5
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks for your help! I will still need a bit to find solutions like this...